# In Crystal Reports, can you group by two tables which are both many-to-one with the top group?

Tags: crystal-reports

I am working on a Crystal Report that breaks down data first by Receipt ID, and then I need two groups both under Receipt ID, but that aren't related to each other.

So instead of three levels of grouping, I need to somehow have only two levels like following:

```
Group: Receipt_ID
    Group: Receipt_Detail.Line_Number
    Group: Receipt_Deduction.Description
```

Here is an example of what it should look like:

```
Receipt ID    Line Number    Weight  Dollar Amount
091911001
                   1         17,640  $2116.80
                   2         16,860  $1180.20
                   3         17,200  $1204.00

            MAC Peeler Rate  17,640   0.0027
            MAC Juicer Rate  34,060   0.0011

091911007
                   1         40,000  $10050.00
                   2         13,500  $2600.00

            MACMA Rate       53,500   0.0350

And so on.
```

Is there anyway to do this sort of thing in Crystal Reports 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subreport! That would be the cleanest way.

1. In the receipt ID footer, insert a subreport.
2. In the subreport, use the `Receipt_Deduction` table.
3. In Subreport Links, select records in the subreport based on `Receipt_ID = Receipt_Deduction.Receipt_ID`
4. Move your deductions content to the subreport's detail section.
5. In the parent report, remove the `Receipt_Deduction` group, and perhaps the detail table too.
6. If you want, you could even move your detail content to the Detail section, so you can remove the `Receipt_Detail` group.

Comment: Sounds like a good way to go. I've not used subreports before so it should be interesting to try. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: I am trying this right now, but I get all deductions for all receipts rather than the deductions for the receipt in question.

Comment: Sweet. Yes, that's what I was trying to say in #3. I'll edit to clarify.